# Dask: create strictly increasing index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

As is well documented, Dask creates a strictly increasing index on a per partition basis when `reset_index` is called, resulting in duplicate indices over the whole set. What is the best way (e.g. computationally quickest) to create a strictly increasing index in Dask - which doesn't have to be consecutive - over the whole set? I was hoping `map_partitions` would pass in the partition number, but I don't think it does. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks @MRocklin, I've got this far, but I need a little assistance on how to recombine my series with the original dataframe.

```
def create_increasing_index(ddf:dd.DataFrame):
    mps = int(len(ddf) / ddf.npartitions + 1000)
    values = ddf.index.values

    def do(x, max_partition_size, block_id=None):
        length = len(x)
        if length == 0:
            raise ValueError("Does not work with empty partitions. Consider using dask.repartition.")

        start = block_id[0] * max_partition_size
        return da.arange(start, start+length, chunks=1)

    series = values.map_blocks(do, max_partition_size=mps, dtype=np.int64)
    ddf2 = dd.concat([ddf, dd.from_array(series)], axis=1)
    return ddf2
```

Where I'm getting the error "ValueError: Unable to concatenate DataFrame with unknown division specifying axis=1". Is there a better way than using dd.concat? Thanks.

**EDIT AGAIN**

Actually, for my purposes (and amounts of data that I was testing on - only a few gb) cumsum is fast enough. I'll revisit when this becomes too slow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather slow way of accomplishing this would be to create a new column and then use `cumsum`

```
ddf['x'] = 1
ddf['x'] = ddf.x.cumsum()
ddf = ddf.set_index('x', sorted=True)
```

This is neither very slow nor is it free.

Given how your question is phrased I suspect that you are looking to just create a range for each partition that is separated by a very large value that you know to be larger than the largest number of rows.  You're right that `map_partitions` doesn't provide the partition number.  You could do one of the two solutions below instead.

1. Convert to a dask.array (with `.values`), use the `map_blocks` method, which does provide a block index, and then convert back to a series with `dd.from_array`.
2. Convert to a list of dask.delayed objects, create the delayed series' yourself, and then convert back to a dask series with `dd.from_delayed`

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html

Comment: I am not sure this is reliable, I have got unreproducible results. Sometime I have unique values sometime I have got some duplicates.